# Basic issues with running python on Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio set up.

Two really basic questions.

1. Is it possible to run cells like:

   ```
   #%%
   print("hello world")
   #%%
   print("What is going on") 
   #%%
   ```

And I want to run each block (#%%) separately and see the result in a "console." How do I open a console?

Comment: No Visual Studio does not support that kind of Jupyter Notebook execution, it executes the program as a whole from the first line to the last

Comment: You seem to be asking for a notebook feature with cells - This is for .NET code, not Python - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MLNET.notebook (Note: Visual Studio **Code** handles this separately https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/educators/notebooks )

Answer (score 0):

Where there is a will there is a way.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py

This will ALSO work on Visual Studio

You have to start a block at the beginning of the program.

To run the first block

so

```
#%%
import os,sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#%%
```

will work once you hit Ctrl+Enter

Will see about the console thing and when I find an answer will post.

Edit: Works just fine! you can see the results in the interactive window that pops up! Beauty!!

I now have to find variable window and all that fun but so far so good.

Thanks.